Alternating page count when attempting to ensure page numbers are a multiple of four
I would like to ensure that my page count is a multiple of four. If it isn't a multiple of four, I would like to add \newpage\begin{center}\textbf{BLANK PAGE}\end{center} until I reach the page count is a multiple of four. I am primitively attempting to use the expl3 solution documented in this answer with the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount, lastpage}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\begin{center}\textbf{BLANK PAGE}\end{center}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ensurefour} { }
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn
   { \int_mod:nn { 4 - \int_mod:nn { \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} } { 4 } } { 4 } }
   { \blankpage }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test\newpage

\ensurefour
\end{document}

When I compile it for the first time with any engine, it produces an output of one page, i.e. a single page that says "Test". When I compile it a second time, it produces an output of four pages, which is the desired output.
But when I continue to compile it for the third time, without removing the .aux file, the page number returns to 1.
This is because, during the first compilation, LaTeX writes the following to the .aux file:
\relax 
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{1}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{1}
\gdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}

Therefore, in the second compilation, \getpagerefnumber{LastPage} sees "1", and \ensurefour proceeds to add 3 pages to make 4 pages total. But then it sees that four pages are produced, so it writes to the aux file:
\relax 
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{4}}
\xdef\lastpage@lastpage{4}
\gdef\lastpage@lastpageHy{}
\gdef \@abspage@last{4}

Which causes the third compilation to think that there are already four pages, so no further pages are added, leaving us with only one page... and so on.
Question: Is there a way to make the page numbers converge to 4, without alternating between 1 and 4?

Unfortunately, something changed in the management of lastpage which makes the previous solution unsuitable.

Unfortunately, the package lastpage changed the way it manages the label and now it uses the hook afterlastpage.
You can issue \clearpage and use the current value of page.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\blankpage}{\begin{center}\textbf{BLANK PAGE}\end{center}\clearpage}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ensurefour} { }
 {
  \clearpage
  \prg_replicate:nn
   { \int_mod:nn { 4 - \int_mod:nn { \value{page}-1 } { 4 } } { 4 } }
   { \blankpage }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtEndDocument{\ensurefour}

\begin{document}

Test
%\newpage
test
%\newpage
test
%\newpage
test

\end{document}

Uncommenting the \newpage commands will show the correct result.

You need not to label to the last page. The \ensurefor macro can run \vfill\break first (or \vfill\supereject if you have floats in the document). Then the last real page is finished and you are sure that \pageno is equal to n+1 where n is the number of real pages. You can add desired bank pages using the \pageno register.
Another advance of this solution is that you don't need to wait to the second TeX run for the correct number of pages.
I can show you how to do this in OpTeX. A LaTeX solution can be analogical.
\newcount\restpages
\def\ensurefour{\vfill\break
   \restpages = \expr[0]{ 4 - (\the\pageno-1)\%4 }\relax
   \ifnum\restpages=4 \restpages=0 \fi
   \fornum 1..\restpages \do{\null\vfill\break}
}

Test:
\lipsum[1-10]

\ensurefour

\bye


A quick and dirty solution would be labeling LastPage (or an equivalent) before \ensurefour produces extra pages. For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\begin{center}\textbf{BLANK PAGE}\end{center}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ensurefour} { }
        {
                \label{LastPageBeforeEnsureFour}
                \prg_replicate:nn
                { \int_mod:nn { 4 - \int_mod:nn { \getpagerefnumber{LastPageBeforeEnsureFour} } { 4 } } { 4 } }
                { \blankpage }
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test

\ensurefour
\end{document}


I produce printed documents with a pages number multiple of four and where I want to put some specific content on the last or two last pages. Here are the commands I wrote for this purpose.
I get the number of current physical pages through \ReadonlyShipoutCounter (number of already created full pages, add one to take into account the current one)
\newcommand{\theabsolutepage}{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}

I define a command \blankpage which allows to set the page style (\blankpage[plain] if you want the plain page style for the blank pages)
\NewDocumentCommand{\blankpage}{ O{empty} }
% #1: page style for the blank page
{
  \clearpage{}\thispagestyle{#1}\null\clearpage{}
}

and a command \clearpagestoend to obtain the desired number of blank pages
\NewDocumentCommand{\clearpagestoend}{ O{0} O{empty} }
% #1: number of reserved pages at end
% #2: page style for blank pages
{
  \clearpage{\pagestyle{#2}}
  \count255=\theabsolutepage \advance \count255 by #1 \advance \count255 by -1
  \count254=\count255 
  \divide \count254 by 4 \multiply \count254 by 4
  \advance \count255 by -\count254
  \ifcase\count255  % pages nb % 4 == 0: do nothing
    \relax
  \or               % pages nb % 4 == 1: skip 3 pages
    \blankpage[#2]  \blankpage[#2] \blankpage[#2]
  \or               % pages nb % 4 == 2: skip 2 pages
    \blankpage[#2]  \blankpage[#2]
  \or               % pages nb % 4 == 3: skip 1 page
    \blankpage{\pagestyle{#2}}
  \fi
}

For example
\clearpagestoend[2][plain]

generate the number of blank pages to obtain a pages number multiple of four minus 2 pages with the plain page style.
Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\theabsolutepage}{\inteval{\ReadonlyShipoutCounter+1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\blankpage}{ O{empty} }
% #1: page style for the blank page
{
  \clearpage{}\thispagestyle{#1}\null\clearpage{}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\clearpagestoend}{ O{0} O{empty} }
% #1: number of reserved pages at end
% #2: page style for blank pages
{
  \clearpage{\pagestyle{#2}}
  \count255=\theabsolutepage \advance \count255 by #1 \advance \count255 by -1
  \count254=\count255
  \divide \count254 by 4 \multiply \count254 by 4
  \advance \count255 by -\count254
  \ifcase\count255  % pages nb % 4 == 0: do nothing
    \relax
  \or               % pages nb % 4 == 1: skip 3 pages
    \blankpage[#2]  \blankpage[#2] \blankpage[#2]
  \or               % pages nb % 4 == 2: skip 2 pages
    \blankpage[#2]  \blankpage[#2]
  \or               % pages nb % 4 == 3: skip 1 page
    \blankpage{\pagestyle{#2}}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\clearpagestoend

\end{document}

